# How to Disallow Concatenated Selectors

Tags: sass, stylelint, sass-lint

I found this sass feature as hard to catch some missing styles and would like to lint my project on it. Here is the link to feature documentation:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector#adding-suffixes

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Stylelint's [`selector-disallowed-list`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/selector-disallowed-list/) rule to disallow concatenated selectors.

For example, to disallow the suffix examples in the Sass docs you can use:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "selector-disallowed-list": ["/^&__/", "/^&--/"]
  }
}
```

This will disallow selectors that start with `&__` or `&--`, e.g.:

```
.foo {
  &__bar {}
  &--baz {}
}
```

But not:

```
.foo {
  &::before {}
  &:hover {}
  & .bar {}
  &.baz {}
}
```